# Eclipse call ViewPart saveState on View close

Tags: eclipse-plugin, savestate, memento

I have a Eclipse plugin that uses a view which extends `ViewPart`. `ViewPart` has a `saveState` method which requires an `IMemento`.

I added my code to `saveState` and the corresponding `init` method and it works. Unfortunately, `saveState` is only called if the entire workspace is shutting down. My view is not of such great importance that I can expect it to be opened the entire time. Hence, it would be cool if `saveState` would be called on view closure.

I found a view-part listener as mean to react on view closure, but what I do not get is where the `IMemento` comes from. Where do I get the memento object that is used on workspace closure? Or where do I have to store my own memento object to make the view part use it in the `init` method if the view is (re)opened?

```
@Override
public void saveState(IMemento memento) {
    super.saveState(memento);
    memento = memento.createChild(MEMENTO_GUI_STATE);
    memento.putBoolean(MEMENTO_IS_FLAT, !isHierarchicalModeActive());
    memento.putBoolean(MEMENTO_IS_CATEGORY_MODE_ACTIVE, comboViewer.isVisible());
}
```

This is my `saveState` - can I tell my view somehow tell to call it every time the view closes?

Comment: could you please provide your saveState method

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [question](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_does_a_view_persist_its_state_between_sessions%3F) in the Eclipse FAQ:

> Storing view state is done in two commons ways, depending on whether
>   you want to store settings between workbench sessions or across
>   invocations of your view. The first of these facilities is found
>   directly on IViewPart. When the workbench is shut down, the method
>   saveState is called on all open views.
>
> Another mechanism for persisting view state is the JFace
>   IDialogSettings facility. The advantage of dialog settings over the
>   view save/init mechanism is that you can control when settings are
>   persisted. The saveState method is called only if your view is open
>   when the workbench shuts down, so it is not useful for storing view
>   state when the view is closed by the user. Dialog settings, on the
>   other hand, can be changed and persisted whenever you want.

Go to this other [question](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_save_settings_for_a_dialog_or_wizard%3F) or to the [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/dialogs_settings.htm) itself for the settings mechanism.

Comment: Having just ran into this problem I came to the conclusion that for saving state for a view, the DialogSettings works best, leaving the memento to the Workbench's saving of view size, location etc. The DialogSettings are simple retrieved from the plug-in: Activator.getDefault().getDialogSettings();

Answer (score 2):

Well this could be "a bit" ugly but nothing else came to my mind: store memento variable as a field variable, initialize it in your `init(IViewSite site, IMemento memento)` method, override `dispose()` and call `saveState(IMemento memento)` explicitely.

Comment: `dispose()` of the `View` might be called after the `Widget`s have been disposed, resulting in a `org.eclipse.swt.SWTException`: Widget is disposed when trying to save the state of those widgets

Answer (score 0):

You can read and write your own XMLMemento from your `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getStateLocation()` at any time you want.  As @BelaViser mentioned, you could write your file in your `IViewPart#dispose()` method and read it in your view constructor.