# Eclipse 4.2(juno) did not call saveState method of ViewPart when workspace is closing

Tags: eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin, perspective

I have a eclipse-plugin that have two perspectives. There is a view which extends ViewPart in one of the two perspectives. In this view, I overrided saveState method of ViewPart to save my data.

First, I open the prespective that has this view. Then i add some data in the view which should be save in saveState. 
Next, I navigate to the other perspective that does not have this view. 
Finally, I close the eclipse's workspace.

In eclipse 4.2(juno), saveState method of the view do not have been called. My data lost.
In eclipse 3.6(Helios), saveState method of the view have been called. My date has been persisted.

Does anyone know the reason? How can I insure that the saveState will be called when closing the workspace on all version of eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse e4 has no ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor class and the application model has no property to set this,totally different with Eclipse 3.x.
You can get more from the [wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/EAS/State_Persistence#e4_.28Java.29) and [vogella tutorial blog](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/10/17/saveandrestore-e4/).

Answer (score 0):

With joy, this problem persists into 4.4.2.

At its base, the issue is the compatibility layer WorkbenchPart.getViewReferences() only searches the currently active perspective. This behavior is different than the 3.x. The relevant code from the 4.4.2 Eclipse WorkbenchPart is here (notice the call to getCurrentPerspective()).

```
    public IViewReference[] getViewReferences() {
    MPerspective perspective = getCurrentPerspective();
    if (perspective != null) {
        List<MPlaceholder> placeholders = modelService.findElements(window, null,
                MPlaceholder.class, null, EModelService.PRESENTATION);
        List<IViewReference> visibleReferences = new ArrayList<IViewReference>();
        for (ViewReference reference : viewReferences) {
            for (MPlaceholder placeholder : placeholders) {
                if (reference.getModel() == placeholder.getRef()
                        && placeholder.isToBeRendered()) {
                    // only rendered placeholders are valid view references
                    visibleReferences.add(reference);
                }
            }
        }
        return visibleReferences.toArray(new IViewReference[visibleReferences.size()]);
    }
    return new IViewReference[0];
}
```

Therefore, if one has a view open and then changes to a perspective where that view is not shown, the saveState() method will not be called.

We have added an OSGI event listener for the UIEvents.UILifeCycle.appShutdownStarted and made a call to the saveState(). However, it is necessary to obtain the IMemento manually, since it is not present. Example code is in the org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2.2/org.eclipse.ui/workbench/3.104.0/org/eclipse/ui/internal/ViewReference.java#ViewReference).

One could also add a part close listener with the IPartListener class to potentially persist settings if the user closes the view rather than application shutting down.

We have not found an OSGI event for the part being closed, but there may be one.

This discussion ([Eclipse call ViewPart saveState on View close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472279/eclipse-call-viewpart-savestate-on-view-close?rq=1)) suggested using IDialogSettings rather the IMemento. This discussion also proposed perhaps adding something into the dispose() method, but it is unclear how many resources are necessarily still available at the point of the dispose() being called.